# Redirect user to a specific page if he acesses a conference with id that dont exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route:

```
Route::get('conference/admin/{id}', 
[ 'uses' => 'ConferenceController@admin', 
'as'=>'conference.admin']);
```

So when the user acesses "http://proj.test/conference/manage/1" it acesses the page homepage of the conference admin area.

But if this specific conference is removed if the user acessses "http://proj.test/conference/admin/1" it appears a page with this message:

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

But, if the conference dont exist and the user acesses  "http://proj.test/conference/admin/1" what should happen is the user be redirected to the homepage ('/').

Do you know how to achieve that?

I already have in the AuthServiceProvider the code below to allow only the user that is the creator of the conference to acess the admin area of that conference. I dont know if this can be used also to redirect the user to ('/') if he acesses a conference that dont exist.

// auth service provider gate

```
 public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        $gate->define('access-management-area', function($user, $conference)
        {
            return $user->id == $conference->organizer_id;
        });
    }
```

Then in the admin() the gate is used:

```
   public function admin($id){
        $conference = Conference::findOrFail($id);
        if(Gate::allows('access-management-area', $conference)) {
            return view('conference.admin')->with('conference',$conference);
        } else {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing a `findOrFail` lookup, this will always return a 404 when it *fails* to find a record.

You could do the following:

```
 public function admin($id){
    $conference = Conference::find($id);

    if(!$conference){
      return redirect('/');
    }

    if(Gate::allows('access-management-area', $conference)) {
        return view('conference.admin')->with('conference',$conference);
    } 
    else{
        abort(403);
    }
 }
```